# Using OpenCV with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, android-studio

I want to use OpenCV within an Android Application that I'm developing. I've tried various methods of importing OpenCV into Android Studio with no success. I tried following this tutorial:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/14546/how-to-work-with-opencv4android-in-android-studio/

However, there is no "Import" option for me. Only "Import Project" and "Import Module". When I try "Import Module", it just says "Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project". I've been getting extremely frustrated trying to import libraries or modules (What's the difference anyways?) with Android Studio and am thinking of just going back to Eclipse. Does anyone else have any suggestions on how I can get OpenCV working in Android Studio? All of the tutorials I've seen either haven't worked for me or are too outdated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I too am facing the same problem. Any success so far ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio allready solved.